# Avoid automatic jitting of jax.numpy functions when using jax.jit

Tags: python, jit, jax

If I call the dummy function defined below, an error will be raised, because `jnp.iscomplex(x)` returns a tracer object.

But x is fixed, thus I'd expect `jnp.iscomplex(x)` to return `False`.

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

x = jnp.array(3)

@jax.jit
def dummy():
  if jnp.iscomplex(x):
    print("Is complex!")
```

Is it possible to avoid jitting `jnp.iscomplex`?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot normally¹ cause part of a JIT-compiled function to be executed outside the JIT context. But you may be able to do what you have in mind by accessing static attributes, namely the dtype:

```py
@jax.jit
def dummy():
  if jnp.issubdtype(x.dtype, jnp.complexfloating):
    print("Is complex!")
```

This has slightly different semantics to `jnp.iscomplex`, which returns `True` or `False` depending on the value of the imaginary part. For some background on why it is not possible to use python control flow conditional on array values in JIT, see [How To Think In JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html).

Alternatively, if you'd like to compute static functions on static values, you can use `numpy` values and functions rather than their `jax.numpy` counterparts:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array(3)

@jax.jit
def dummy():
  if np.iscomplex(x):
    print("Is complex!")
```

---

¹ It is technically possible to do what you want using an [external callback](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/external_callbacks.html), but there are performance implications that mean it's not the right solution in most cases.